# How can we trigger an event from MS Teams (and call an external app) when a new team is created in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When any user creates a new team in MS Teams we want to propagate this information to our custom application and perform some actions. Is there any way to trigger this event ?

Comment: Using Microsoft Graph API, you can subscribe to resources to get change notifications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-change-notifications-overview) to receive webhooks to your own api endpoint.

To receive a webhook for a new [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0), you have to create a new [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription) (See [Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions)) and use `/users/{id}/events` as `resource`. Change `{id}` to the `Id` of the [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user) you want to subscribe to.

Because you only want to receive new events, set `ChangeType` to `created`. You can also use `updated` or `deleted` and to chain them, use `,`.

---

**Example request to create a new subscription**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json
```

```json
{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://yourbackend.tld/api/new-event",
   "resource": "/users/{id}/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2022-05-21T11:21:32.5261217Z",
}
```

---

**expirationDateTime**

Please be aware that the `expirationDateTime` has a maximum value. See [Maximum length of subscription per resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type). The maximum value for events is 4230 minutes.

You can renew a subscription by extending its expiry time, see [Update subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update).

---

**Immutable identifiers for Outlook resources**

I would also recommend to use the header `Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"` to ensure that the `Id` of an event doesn't change over time. Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id).